# How to update statefulWidget data?

Tags: flutter

Like the below code:

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  String name;

  TestWidget(this.name);

  void updateName(String name) {
    //how to update Text data
  }

  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();

}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<KMSelectionItem> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.name);
  }

}
```

I want to change the text data through the method `updateName`. But I don't know how can do it.

Comment: Please check the very basic Flutter state management examples. Even if you create a new, empty Flutter application in VS Code, it will answer your question.

Comment: I have do my best to solve it. Can your give me an answer.@PeterKoltai

Comment: Maybe I should create a new TestWidget to update it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use setState method for this purpose, this method updates the ui based on the changes made. insert the function code like this and declare the function inside your stateful widget. to update the text:

```
class _TestWidgetState extends State<KMSelectionItem> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.name);
  }

      void updateName() {
        //how to update Text data
        setState(() {
              widget.name = YOUR_NEW_TEXT;
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: The method `setState` can use in class `_TestWidgetState `. It can't be invoke in method `updateName`.

Comment: declare the function in _TestWidgetState, I have edited the answer.

Comment: The method `updateName` in class `TestWidget`.

Comment: What is the problem? you should declare the method in the stateful class as I said :\

Answer (score -3):

```
    class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  String name;

  TestWidget(this.name);

 void updateName(String name) {
    setState(() {
          name ="updated_name";
        });
    }

  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();

}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<KMSelectionItem> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.name);
  }

}
```